# Flutter Mac OS Build Error How can I solve the error?

Tags: macos, flutter, build

Build Failed Logs:

```
** BUILD FAILED **
```

Xcode's output:
↳
While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/muratapps/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.12+2/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h:5:
In file included from :1:
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:8:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterAppDelegate.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "FlutterAppDelegate.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<Flutter/FlutterAppDelegate.h>
While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/muratapps/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.12+2/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h:5:
In file included from :1:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:8:
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:10:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterMacros.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "FlutterMacros.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<Flutter/FlutterMacros.h>
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterPlugin.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "FlutterPlugin.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<Flutter/FlutterPlugin.h>
While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/muratapps/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.12+2/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h:5:
In file included from :1:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:8:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlugin.h:11:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterBinaryMessenger.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "FlutterBinaryMessenger.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<Flutter/FlutterBinaryMessenger.h>
While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/muratapps/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.12+2/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h:5:
In file included from :1:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:8:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlugin.h:11:
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterBinaryMessenger.h:10:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterMacros.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "FlutterMacros.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<Flutter/FlutterMacros.h>
While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/muratapps/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.12+2/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h:5:
In file included from :1:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:8:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlugin.h:12:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterChannels.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "FlutterChannels.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<Flutter/FlutterChannels.h>
While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/muratapps/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.12+2/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h:5:
In file included from :1:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:8:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlugin.h:12:
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterChannels.h:8:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterBinaryMessenger.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "FlutterBinaryMessenger.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<Flutter/FlutterBinaryMessenger.h>
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterChannels.h:9:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterCodecs.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "FlutterCodecs.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<Flutter/FlutterCodecs.h>
While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/muratapps/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.12+2/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h:5:
In file included from :1:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:8:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlugin.h:12:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterChannels.h:9:
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterCodecs.h:9:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterMacros.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "FlutterMacros.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<Flutter/FlutterMacros.h>
While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/muratapps/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.12+2/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h:5:
In file included from :1:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:8:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlugin.h:13:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterCodecs.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "FlutterCodecs.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<Flutter/FlutterCodecs.h>
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlugin.h:14:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterPlatformViews.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "FlutterPlatformViews.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<Flutter/FlutterPlatformViews.h>
While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/muratapps/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.12+2/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h:5:
In file included from :1:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:8:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlugin.h:14:
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlatformViews.h:10:9: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterCodecs.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#import "FlutterCodecs.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<Flutter/FlutterCodecs.h>
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlatformViews.h:11:9: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterMacros.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#import "FlutterMacros.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<Flutter/FlutterMacros.h>
While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/muratapps/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.12+2/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h:5:
In file included from :1:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:8:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:

```
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:16:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterMacros.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "FlutterMacros.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <Flutter/FlutterMacros.h>
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:17:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterPlatformViews.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "FlutterPlatformViews.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <Flutter/FlutterPlatformViews.h>
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:18:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterPlugin.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "FlutterPlugin.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <Flutter/FlutterPlugin.h>
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:19:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterPluginAppLifeCycleDelegate.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "FlutterPluginAppLifeCycleDelegate.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <Flutter/FlutterPluginAppLifeCycleDelegate.h>
While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/muratapps/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.12+2/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h:5:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:19:
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPluginAppLifeCycleDelegate.h:8:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterPlugin.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "FlutterPlugin.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <Flutter/FlutterPlugin.h>
While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/muratapps/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.12+2/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h:5:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:20:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterTexture.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "FlutterTexture.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <Flutter/FlutterTexture.h>
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:21:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterViewController.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "FlutterViewController.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <Flutter/FlutterViewController.h>
While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/muratapps/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.12+2/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h:5:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:21:
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterViewController.h:11:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterBinaryMessenger.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "FlutterBinaryMessenger.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <Flutter/FlutterBinaryMessenger.h>
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterViewController.h:12:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterDartProject.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "FlutterDartProject.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <Flutter/FlutterDartProject.h>
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterViewController.h:13:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterEngine.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "FlutterEngine.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <Flutter/FlutterEngine.h>
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterViewController.h:14:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterMacros.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "FlutterMacros.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <Flutter/FlutterMacros.h>
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterViewController.h:15:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterPlugin.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "FlutterPlugin.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <Flutter/FlutterPlugin.h>
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterViewController.h:16:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterTexture.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "FlutterTexture.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <Flutter/FlutterTexture.h>
46 warnings generated.
46 warnings generated.
/Users/muratapps/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inapp_purchase-2.3.2/ios/Classes/FlutterInappPurchasePlugin.m:45:52: warning: assigning to 'id<IAPPromotionObserverDelegate>' from incompatible type 'FlutterInappPurchasePlugin *__strong'
    [IAPPromotionObserver sharedObserver].delegate = self;
                                                   ^ ~~~~
/Users/muratapps/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inapp_purchase-2.3.2/ios/Classes/FlutterInappPurchasePlugin.m:200:79: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'SKPaymentTransactionState' (aka 'enum SKPaymentTransactionState') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                                     [NSNumber numberWithInt: item.transactionState], @"transactionStateIOS",
                                                     ~                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/muratapps/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inapp_purchase-2.3.2/ios/Classes/FlutterInappPurchasePlugin.m:590:71: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'SKPaymentTransactionState' (aka 'enum SKPaymentTransactionState') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                             [NSNumber numberWithInt: transaction.transactionState], @"transactionStateIOS",
                                             ~                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
3 warnings generated.
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBWrappers.pbobjc.m:11:
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBUtilities.h:33:9: warning: double-quoted include "GPBArray.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#import "GPBArray.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
        <GPBArray.h>
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBStruct.pbobjc.m:11:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBProtocolBuffers_RuntimeSupport.h:40:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBUtilities_PackagePrivate.h:33:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBUtilities.h:33:
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBArray.h:33:9: warning: double-quoted include "GPBRuntimeTypes.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#import "GPBRuntimeTypes.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        <GPBRuntimeTypes.h>
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBStruct.pbobjc.m:11:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBProtocolBuffers_RuntimeSupport.h:40:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBUtilities_PackagePrivate.h:33:
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBUtilities.h:34:9: warning: double-quoted include "GPBMessage.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#import "GPBMessage.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        <GPBMessage.h>
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBUtilities.h:35:9: warning: double-quoted include "GPBRuntimeTypes.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#import "GPBRuntimeTypes.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        <GPBRuntimeTypes.h>
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBStruct.pbobjc.m:11:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBProtocolBuffers_RuntimeSupport.h:40:
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBUtilities_PackagePrivate.h:35:9: warning: double-quoted include "GPBDescriptor_PackagePrivate.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#import "GPBDescriptor_PackagePrivate.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        <GPBDescriptor_PackagePrivate.h>
22 warnings generated.
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBSourceContext.pbobjc.m:11:
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBProtocolBuffers_RuntimeSupport.h:34:9: warning: double-quoted include "GPBBootstrap.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#import "GPBBootstrap.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        <GPBBootstrap.h>
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBProtocolBuffers_RuntimeSupport.h:34:9: warning: double-quoted include "GPBBootstrap.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#import "GPBBootstrap.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        <GPBBootstrap.h>
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBProtocolBuffers_RuntimeSupport.h:36:9: warning: double-quoted include "GPBDescriptor_PackagePrivate.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#import "GPBDescriptor_PackagePrivate.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        <GPBDescriptor_PackagePrivate.h>
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBAny.pbobjc.m:11:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBProtocolBuffers_RuntimeSupport.h:36:
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBDescriptor_PackagePrivate.h:35:9: warning: double-quoted include "GPBDescriptor.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#import "GPBDescriptor.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        <GPBDescriptor.h>
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBAny.pbobjc.m:11:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBProtocolBuffers_RuntimeSupport.h:36:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBDescriptor_PackagePrivate.h:35:
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBDescriptor.h:33:9: warning: double-quoted include "GPBRuntimeTypes.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#import "GPBRuntimeTypes.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        <GPBRuntimeTypes.h>
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBAny.pbobjc.m:11:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBProtocolBuffers_RuntimeSupport.h:36:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBDescriptor_PackagePrivate.h:35:
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBDescriptor.h:33:


/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBUtilities.h:33:9: warning: double-quoted include "GPBArray.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#import "GPBArray.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
        <GPBArray.h>
In file included from 
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
        <pb_encode.h>
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/nanopb/nanopb-umbrella.h:22:9: error: double-quoted include "pb_common.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Werror,-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#import "pb_common.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
        <pb_common.h>
13 errors generated.
In file included from /Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCCTLibrary/Protogen/nanopb/cct.nanopb.c:20:
/Users/muratapps/Documents/MobileProjects/flutter_app/ios/Pods/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCCTLibrary/Protogen/nanopb/cct.nanopb.h:22:10: fatal error: could not build module 'nanopb'
#include <nanopb/pb.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^
14 errors generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'GoogleDataTransport' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'url_launcher' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'path_provider' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'shared_preferences' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'device_info' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'package_info' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'flutter_inapp_purchase' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'Protobuf' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'fluttertoast' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'Firebase' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseMessaging' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstallations' from project 'Pods')
warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone SE (2nd generation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a cocoapods issue caused by a recommended build setting. A fix is at CocoaPods/CocoaPods#9905 and targeted for CocoaPods 1.10. As a (temporary) workaround you can set "Quoted include in framework headers" in pods project build settings to NO.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to run it on the phone with this method. So if I print out like this, will the application be published?

Comment: Its just a clang setting so yes it shouldn't matter for publishing. If the answers works for you please accept it :)

Comment: But not that once you do a pod update or install you need to repeat this. Try to update cocoapods to 1.10 to get completely rid of it. Otherwise i'd recommend to include a loop in the pod file to automatically set this option.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this as wel. To make it more clear where to search:
In your flutter project go to:
IOS - Runner.xcodeproj --> open file: project.pbxproj
search for this value: `CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER = YES;`
change it to: `CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER = NO;`

rerun you project build.
There is a chance the build might fail. In this case clear everything from the debug build directory:
...yourapp/build/ios/Debug-ihponeos

Comment: Note that I found not 1 but 3 `CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER` values to set to 'NO' in the file `project.pbxproj`

Comment: Works in the iOS simulator (12 Pro Max) but failed on my device (XS Max) even after cleaning the `myapp/build/ios/Debug-ihponeos` directory

Comment: Forgot to add that I have no specific error message after the error occured alert popup even in XCode! No Idea what is the problem ...

Comment: Re-tried and finally got the following error message: `Runner.app/Info.plist does not exist. The Flutter "Thin Binary" build phase must run after "Copy Bundle Resources".`